# In Django's template system, how do I make it to do different things sometimes?

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

```
{% for p in posts %}
    <div style="width:50px;">
    blah
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, what if I want the div to be 100px 75% of the time? 25% of the time? Randomized.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: is this for split-path Testing (or AB Testing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic does not go into templates.

Solution: write a new template tag that returns a random number, and use that for the width.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

Your template would then look like:

```
{% for p in posts %}
    <div style="width:{% myrandomtag 0 100 %}px;">
    blah
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or whatever. Put your required logic in the python code for the tag.

Answer (score 2):

[`random` filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#random) should do the thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's [cycle](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) method:

```
{% for o in some_list %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
    ...
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My first answer was given in Jinja's format, using it's `cycler` functionality, which isn't present in Django :/